# check if a line is valid or not in Java

Tags: java, validation

I would like to perform checking on the following:

```
VALID LINES;
/**/ some code
*/ some code   /** dsfsdkf sd**/

NOT VALID LINES;
/**/ //some code
*/ /***/ //somecode
```

So basically if there is a line of code outside a comment it is valid, otherwise not.

What would be the best way to tackle this kind of validation?

Note:
For     `*/` I assume that the `/*` has been opened some lines before.

Comment: A regular expression would be an obvious thing to use for this kind of problem.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. Cant use them, to slow.

Comment: Are you trying to validate java code or validate that using java?

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. How can you know that a regular expression will be too slow before you've even tried it?

Comment: I am trying to read all lines of code from a .java file, excluding comments.

Comment: Can we get a bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish?  This is a narrow question that might be barking up the wrong tree altogether for your goals.

Comment: How about `javac`? It's open source and everything.

Comment: I can't imagine regex to be too slow here, except you need to do this a gazillion times. regex can be fast, and regex can be slow, depending on how you use it. You can of course parse manually, like going to the file character by character and checking your desired conditions. Be prepared for extra work with quotes etc which you will probably like to ignore.

Comment: if you want your regex to be fast make sure you reuse a compiled pattern (and if possible, a matcher)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be quite fast I believe.

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/Test.java"));

        final String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String line;
        while (null != (line = r.readLine()))
            buf.append(line).append(nl);

        for (String code : buf.toString().split("(?ms)/\\*.*?\\*/|//[^\\n]*"))
            System.out.println(code);
    }
}
```

If you read up a bit on the internals of reg-exps you'll realize that regular expressions are quite efficient once the underlying automaton has been compiled and minimized (at least for simple regular expressions like the one above). No matter how you implement your algorithm, it would still need to do roughly the same work that the reg-exp engine does in this scenario anyway.

(If you look at the `String.split` method, you'll note that the internal regular expression is compiled into a `Pattern` once and for all.)

Comment: Do you have to omit the braces in the while and for to feel you're doing it fast? ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a Java parser to parse the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom parser with something like [Javacc](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) and then use it to parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to read all lines of code from a .java file, excluding comments.

(Are you trying to extract the code, or simply count the lines of code?)

A simple line-by-line approach you is probably not going to be entirely accurate.  For example consider this:

```
/*  The next line is wrong:
    res = 1 / 0;
 */
```

A line-by-line analysis will conclude that the second line is code ... when it is actually comment.

Another problem with trying to use regexes is that there are all sorts of edge cases.  For example:

```
System.err.println("/* hello mum ");
System.err.println("*/");
```

Or

```
\u002f* This is a comment *\u002f
```

I'm not saying that regexes *cannot* be used.  I'm just saying that your code will be simpler and probably less fragile if you use proper Java parser.